# How to keep my Windows settings and apps after formatting or changing computer?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

So this is a situation i have from time to time.

I'm a software developer and my development environment is very complex, with a lot of services, applications and settings. And everytime i need to move a new machine, i usually loose several days making all these things again.

What would be the best way to keep all my environment settings when i format or move to a new machine ?

I know a way would be by using VirtualBox to create a virtual machine and just copy the VM file to new computer. But as you know, virtualizon degrades the performance and would not make much sense to virtualize Windows inside Windows...

There must be a better way !

Comment: “What would be the best way to keep all my environment settings when i format or move to a new machine?” - Create a custom Windows image and deploy it.

Comment: As @Ramhound states, there is the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-mdt/create-a-windows-10-reference-image . That said, a new PC might have different capabilities from the base. And, as you state, it may take days to set things up to your satisfaction. *Been there, done that.*

Comment: I have substantially reduced customizations. I can be up and running in a day and can do customizations as I work.

Comment: As for the reason I am not submitting an answer that documents how to create your own windows image, that’s because while not complicated, it’s a substantial process that is entirely reliant on what your customizing about the image.

Comment: every migration tool I have used fails or misses something - it's not like a mac where you get exactly where you need to me with a new machine - I have always found that creating a new administrative user can sometimes be nearly as good ....  if the task (In my case anyway) can be really daunting

Comment: @JohnnyVegas - The only migration tool you need is Windows, but the only rule is, you can’t install an old build. It also has to be done from within Windows. I have never had it fail. You should do research on the subject. Custom windows images are properly and relatively easy to create

Comment: If there was a way to transfer settings and apps, I never found one (and I searched). You may transplant the old disk (or its image) into the new computer, and fix any missing drivers and Windows activation, but the results might not be satisfactory.